# Does a (finite) planar graph with minimum degree 3 contain a neighbourhood consisting of bounded degree vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Does a (finite) planar graph $G$ with minimum degree 3 contain a vertex $v$ for which all vertices of distance r=2 neighbourhood consisting of bounded degree vertices?

If this is true, does it still work for larger r and on bounded genus graphs?

Somewhat motivated by [Can the vertices of a planar graph of min degree 3 be covered with edges of average weight ( sum of degrees) at most 14?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3321475/can-the-vertices-of-a-planar-graph-of-min-degree-3-be-covered-with-edges-of-aver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason why this should be the case, or why your condition about degree 2 is here. You can take a tree embedded in the plane such that each vertex has countably infinite valence.

Comment: sorry I should have said no vertices of degree 2 or less

Comment: That still doesn't exclude the example I've given. I'm not really sure what you're looking for.

Comment: Are you talking about an infinite graph?  If so let me clarify I'm talking about finite graphs.

Comment: Meaning finite vertex set? Well then your question is clearly true because the degrees of all vertices are bounded by just the maximum degree.

Comment: I mean is there some constant K such that for any finite planar graph of minimum degree 3 we can find a neighbourhood where all the vertices have degree less than K.

Comment: How about you take a $K+1$-regular tree with some finite number of levels, radiating out from a central vertex, and then connect the leaves in a circle. All of the leaves will have valence 3, but everything else will have valence $K+1$.